# Problems while storing new files into a relative directory path?

Tags: python, python-3.x, io, relative-path

I'm retrieving from the some files as follows:

```
with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
    f.close()
return local_filename
```

The issue is that all the files are being saved into the same directory of my python script. How can I specify another relative directory to save my files?. I tried this:

```
with open(os.path.join(path, local_filename, 'wb')) as f:
```

However, it returned me:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../files/resul_pe056_16.pdf/wb'
```

Therefore, which is the correct way of store my downloaded content into a relative path?.

Comment: try this with open(os.path.join(path, local_filename), 'wb') as f:

Comment: All ready tried that one.... I got `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` @Shijo

Comment: It should work there is something wrong in the statement that you wrote, it works for me  with open(os.path.join(path, local_filename), 'wb') as f:
  f.write('dd')
  f.close()

Comment: @Shijo: Seems obvious that `open(os.path.join(path, local_filename), 'wb') ` is not the same as the OP's `open(os.path.join(path, local_filename, 'wb'))` which also joins the `'wb'` open mode to the resulting path (and leaves the argument out of the call to `open()`).

Comment: I'm voting to close because it's just a typo. it's obvious that `wb` got took for a part of the path. not downvoting because the format of the question is good, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick hopefully:

```
with open(os.path.join(path, local_filename), 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
return local_filename
```

The problem was that you had a bracket in a different place `open(os.path.join(path, local_filename, 'wb'))`. This was actually joining path, local_path and "wb" whereas "wb" was meant for `open` not `join`.

Also the `f.close()` isn't required because the `with ... return` structure does this for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think you could have explained better why it didn't work earlier. posting working code without any explanation helps a little bit, but it's better with words. Specially with comments above telling the same thing, and also because it's really a trivial fix. Better to bring more than the fix (like the `f.close()` thing for instance) so your post is even more useful

Comment: Thanks for the advice.